# Role based user access to LUIS Utterence alone in LUIS portal

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I want to give users *permission* to only **add utterances** to *Intents* which owner gave them access.

Author is one who should have full access like adding, removing or modifying Entity, Intent, Etc,..

There is concept called collaborate but that will have all access to author the model, train and publish which doesn't seems to really good.

Is there concept with role based actions in LUIS portal or is Microsoft is coming up with in latest luis portal which is under preview now .

Any help is appreciated. Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no such provision to allow the users to just get the permission to add utterances to intents. Role based assignments do not allow you to give access to users just to add utterances and are basically classified as contributors, collaborators, owner and so on. LUIS allows you to collaborate and contribute with Azure AD and RBAC based on [Azure Active Directory resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-collaborate#azure-active-directory-resources) and [Azure Active Directory tenant user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-collaborate#azure-active-directory-tenant-user).

You can request for this feature by posting the idea on the [feedback forum](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/356325-general-feedback) for cognitive services.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer so that it helps others as well? Thanks